# Formik + Yup, array being converted to object and then failing validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I have an array of filters with the following Yup schema:

```js
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  filters: Yup.array().strict().of(
    Yup.array().strict().of(
      Yup.object().shape({
        // This isn't important
      })
    )
  )
});
```

When I open the page, the form has the following data (ie the value of `formik.value`):

```
{
  "filters": [
    [
      {
        "type": "samplemeta",
        "cmp": "lt",
        "key": "fastqc__%GC",
        "value": [
          "50"
        ]
      }
    ]
  ],
}
```

Now for some reason, the validation fails with this error (ie the value of `formik.errors`):

```
{
  "filters": [
    "filters[0] must be a `array` type, but the final value was: `{\n  \"0\": {\n    \"type\": \"\\\"samplemeta\\\"\",\n    \"cmp\": \"\\\"lt\\\"\",\n    \"key\": \"\\\"fastqc__%GC\\\"\",\n    \"value\": [\n      \"\\\"50\\\"\"\n    ]\n  }\n}`."
  ]
}
```

So even though the actual data is apparently valid, my array with the shape `[{}]` is being converted to an object in the shape `{0: {}}`, which is then failing the Yup validation. I don't see how this is happening, when I'm using the `<FieldArray>` component to manage the filters array. You can see this [here](https://github.com/ewels/MegaQC/blob/master/src/trend/newFilter.js#L139) in the source code, which looks like:

```html
 <FieldArray name="filters" render={outerArrayHelpers => (...)}/>
```

Why is this happening, and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is an already-report bug, which I have written up [here](https://github.com/formik/formik/issues/2593). It was originally reported [here](https://github.com/formik/formik/issues/2213), and fixed [here](https://github.com/formik/formik/pull/2265), but wasn't included in 2.1.4. I believe 2.1.5 should have the fix, but in the meantime you can solve this problem using `npm install https://pkg.csb.dev/jaredpalmer/formik/commit/157603ab/formik`, which installs a development version of Formik with the pull request merged.